# Connecting Nodejs with Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, node-modules

I was trying to connect nodejs with mysql(first time).i am following w3schools.
Before running the below code i have installed ('npm install mysql').And the website mentioned ou can download a free MySQL database and Once you have MySQL up and running on your computer, you can access it by using Node.js.

i have installed mysql ,but how to start and run it in windows,please help.

```
var con =mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:" "
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error")
    }
    else
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Comment: Better not to rely on wwwfools, see https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/connect/

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql2  `npm i mysql2`

```
 const mysql = require("mysql2") 

   const pool = mysql.createPool({
          host: "localhost",
          user: "root",
          database: "databasename"
          password: "when you install mysql workbench at a time you set"
    });
    
    module.exports = pool.promise();
```

If not set password on workbench make it empty

Import In your `app.js` or `server.js` if this file outside `app.js` or `server.js` file